# Remove quotes from paste() output in R while preserving the class

Tags: r

I have a dataframe "c1" with one column as "region".

```
sum(is.na(c1$region))
[1] 2

class(c1$region)
[1] "factor"
```

However, when I use paste()

```
f1<-paste("c1","$","region",sep="")

> f1
[1] "c1$region"

> sum(is.na(f1))
[1] 0
```

I tried as.name(f1) and as.symbol(f1). Both convert f1 to the "name" class. noquote(f1) converts the char[1] element to the "noquote" class.

```
> f2<-as.name(f1)

> f2
`c1$region`

> sum(is.na(f2))
[1] 0
Warning message:
In is.na(f2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'symbol'

> class(f2)
[1] "name"
```

I want to retain the class of c1$region while being able to use it in queries such as sum(is.na(f2)). Please help.

Comment: See [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18228613/1478381) for more information on why you can't do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Although it is not a popular method, `sum(is.na(eval(parse(text = f1))))` will work with your `f1`

Comment: Building variable names and indexing as if they were plain strings is a terrible idea in R. Are you sure this is really required? Seems like you should be using proper `list()` objects to store your related data rather than a bunch of different variables in your global environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to do, but maybe this will help:

```
c1 <- data.frame(region=c(letters[1:3], NA))
clust <- 1
variable <- "region"

f1 <- get(paste0("c", clust))[[variable]]   # <--- key step
class(f1)
# [1] "factor"
sum(is.na(f1))
# [1] 1
```

In the key step, we use `get` to fetch the correct cluster data frame using its name as a character vector, and then we use `[[`, which unlike `$`, allows us to use a character variable to specify which column we want.

Comment: @Ujjwal, note MrFlick's comment.  I just got lazy and decided against going on a diatribe, but if you're programmatically referring to variables in your workspace (as is the case with the `cX` variables here), you should really consider having them in a list.